# How to get data from another table and insert into the required table in EF core

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

This is a webapi project in **.NET 5** and **EF Core** version 5.0.9. I am testing this API using Swagger. And the database is **SQLite**.
I have 3 tables **Product**, **StockHeader** and **StockDetail**. StockHeader and StockDetail are in **one-to-many** relationship.
Product table has these columns->

- Id
- Name
- Rate

StockHeader table has these columns->

- HdrId
- DocumentNo
- Sign
- ICollection of the type StockDetail

StockDetail table has these columns->

- Id
- HdrId(Foreign key)
- ProductId
- Rate

So, my requirement is that when I enter the value of productID in stockDetail,it should look upto the Product table, take the rate of that particular Id and write it in my StockDetails' Rate column.
I have to do this in HttpPost.
The problem is that StockDetail should not have any reference property of Product.
How can I achieve this in EF Core?

Comment: `StockDetail should not have any reference property of Product` why? The table obviously has a `ProductId` field, so the `StockDetail` class can (should?) have a `Product` class. EF is an ORM, not a replacement for SQL. It's meant to Map Objects to Relational tables. Objects have relations.

Comment: Yeah I understand and accept what you say. But is there any way we can accomplish the task other than creating relations?

Comment: Why? What do the *classes* look like? You have to load the `Product` row anyway, to get that `Rate` from the database. You can use a LINQ query to only load the `Rate` by ID but even so, you still need to query the database

Comment: In the DbContext, you can override the method `SaveChange`, retrieve the `StockDetail`s where `ProductID` is modified and set `Rate`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is no particular reason. I am just asking out of interest.

Comment: One way or another you have to load that rate. Unless you use a trigger to copy the value on INSERT or UPDATE. It's not a good idea to put business logic in the database though. In this case it looks like you want to store the historical rate at the instance a `StockDetail` was created instead of the current one

Comment: On the other hand, if you always want to use the current rate, putting that `Rate` field in `StockDetail` is a serious bug, as you'll have to update all those fields everry time a product's rate changes

Comment: You can load individual rates with eg `db.Products.Where(p=>p.Id=someId).Select(p=>p.Rate).FirstOrDefault()`. That's the equivalent of `select Rate from Products where ID=@id` called with either ADO.NET's or Dapper's `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: Ok i think there is no other way than to add Product reference in the Stockdetail table. SO now how do I get the rate from product table and insert in Stockdetail. I am using Swagger for inserting data and other operations

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I guess you will have the productId as an input parameter. You just have to make a LINQ query to get the desired product form the Products DbSet.

Try with:

```
var product = dbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == productId);
```

It is good to check if the input parameter (productId) was a valid Id so you can write this:

```
if(product == null)
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid ID", nameof(productId));
```

and after that just assign the Rate so that:

```
Rate = product.Rate;
```

Comment: I'll check and get back to you

Comment: It is throwing the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 0):

Add a simply product property in your stockdetail class and one ienumerable in product class...
And add with fluent api a row in your contex, that map productId with your object product...

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany<StockDetail>(s => s.stockDetaik)
            .WithOne(ad => ad.Product)
            .HasForeignKey<Product>(ad => ad.ProductId);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but what I aimed is to get rate without any relation.

Comment: You need to do 2 query... One for getting product and second for insert and set rate...

Comment: Now I can't I haven't pc... But is the same of @ayankovv... Only one thing using where and after firstordefault...